# Can't set a static IP (Ubuntu 14) "interface eth0 not configured"

Tags: ubuntu, networking, network-interface

I need a static IP-address. I edited `/etc/network/interfaces` like so:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet static
 address 10.255.255.80
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 network 10.255.255.0
 broadcast 10.255.255.255
 gateway 10.255.255.1
 dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

When I run `ifdown eth0` I'm getting this:

```
ifdown: interface eth0 not configured
```

I rebooted the whole PC; when it got back up, `eth0` wasn't even shown by `ifconfig`. I ran:

```
ifup eth0
```

... and the interface initialized correctly. So this kind of solved my problem, but I'm still not sure why `ifdown` complained about `eth0` not being configured and why I had to manually run `ifup eth0` after the reboot.

Comment: You need to add `auto eth0` to make it come up at boot, I think?

Comment: please check, if your interface really is called `eth0` because the naming conventions have changed a while ago for [debian](/https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration) and [Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-configuration.html.en). You can check the names with this command: `ls /sys/class/net/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an explanation for the 3 points you encountered:

@steeldriver explained what was missing to get it working at boot: adding `auto eth0`. The meaning is described in [`interfaces(5)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/interfaces.5.html), bold emphasis mine:

> Lines  beginning  with  the word "auto" are used to identify the
>   physical interfaces to be brought up when ifup is run with the -a
>   option. (**This option is used by the  system boot scripts.**) Physical
>   interface names should follow the word "auto" on the same line. There
>   can be multiple "auto" stanzas.  ifup brings the named interfaces up
>   in the order listed.

`ifconfig`, which is obsolete and should be avoided and replaced with `ip link show` or `ip address show` anyway, doesn't display down interfaces unless adding the option `-a`, so didn't show `eth0`.

[`ifdown`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/ifdown.8.html) complained about the interface state as memorized by [ifupdown](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/ifupdown). State is memorized with interface name in the file (here) `/var/run/network/ifstate.eth0` (once brought up). If `ifdown` doesn't find it as expected (up), it will write it wasn't configured.

Once this has been told, it's quite possible a newer version of Ubuntu (or an other distribution) won't use ifupdown and `interfaces` anymore by default.
UPDATE: as @guntbert points out, Ubuntu 18.04 uses [Netplan](https://netplan.io/) instead.

Comment: Very good point about Ubuntu: currently they use *netplan*, a beast that needs to be configured via `yaml` files in `/etc/netplan`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that. I still would like to know how to configure static address without rebooting computer. I struggled quite a long time with that. After I edited /etc/network/interfaces neither ifup nor ifdown commands worked correctly.

Comment: after editing the configuration `ifdown eth0` (with possible fail) followed by `ifup eth0` should work. If it doesn't, then there's an other problem. anyway it's probably more prudent to do `ifdown eth0` first, *then* edit, then `ifup eth0`